# ES6 member import not working, but default import works

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules

The following code works as expected:

```
// ./mwe/index.js
let foo = () => 'foo';

const Bar = {
    foo
};

export default Bar;

// ./index.js
import Bar from './mwe';

console.log(Bar); // logs an object with a member foo that is a function
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
// ./index.js
import {foo} from './mwe';

console.log(foo); // logs undefined
```

Why doesn't the second variant resolve the member `foo` correctly?

---

I interpret the following statement of [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> Import a single member of a module. This inserts myMember into the current scope.
>
> ```
> import {myMember} from 'my-module';
> ```

as meaning that if the module exports an object like `Bar`, then I can import individual members of `Bar` using that syntax. My understanding is clearly incorrect, as this doesn't work, but why? What part have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES2015 import statements do not destructure objects. They look very much like object destructuring but they are different.

Named imports "destructure" one level deep some `exports` object that represents the whole module itself. So `import {foo} from 'bar'` means `const { foo } = require('bar')` not `const { foo } = require('bar').default`. [Supported statements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

But yet again it is special syntax not object destructuring.

For example you **can not** do

```
import { foo: bar } from 'baz' // syntax error
```

or nested destructuring

```
import { foo: { bar } } from 'baz' // syntax error
```

So you need to either export `foo` as separate named export or use another statement for destructuring

```
import Bar from './mwe'

const { foo} = Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not export `foo`, changing it to `export let foo = () => 'foo';` should work.

Comment: But why don't I export it as the member `foo` of `Bar`? (See my update for clarification of this question.)

Answer (score 1):

You used `export default`, which means only the Bar is exported.

The export default exports only the variable that comes after him.

Comment: But why don't I export it as the member `foo` of `Bar`? (See my update for clarification of this question.)

Comment: Because the import statement is not the destructuring pattern used on objects in es6. You could use the default import from Bar and then access it via `Bar.foo()`, but you can't use the extraction of the field foo with import statement.

Comment: Sorry, answered on not my answer :D